# How would I put “\” in a string without the apostrophe in the front of it being cancelled out?

Tags: lua

For example, if I were to do this:

```lua
    print(“\”)
```

It would say: `unfinished string near: ‘“”’
instead of my expected output of: ‘\’

How would I print this? I have searched on google yet still have yet to find an answer.

Comment: you escape it with another \ , in PIL about halfway down this page https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html they give this example `print("a simpler way: '\\'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash (`\`) is [*escaping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the following character, being the double quote (`"`), causing the string to be unfinished.

To include an actual backslash in your string, you escape it with another backslash:

```
print("\\")
```

From [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.1), §3.1 (emphasis mine):

> A short literal string can be delimited by matching single or double quotes, and can contain the following C-like escape sequences: '\a' (bell), '\b' (backspace), '\f' (form feed), '\n' (newline), '\r' (carriage return), '\t' (horizontal tab), '\v' (vertical tab), **'\\' (backslash)**, '"' (quotation mark [double quote]), and ''' (apostrophe [single quote]). [...]

Comment: And colors like: ```print('\'\\x1b[1;32m\' makes a bright \x1b[1;32mgreen\x1b[0m on my terminal')```